# Can't deploy to localhost with PhpStorm

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I installed LAMP using

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

I configured PhpStorm to use **/var/www** folder as root deployment folder, also specified `http://localhost` as web-server root url:
[image]

When I deploy my index.html page with "helloworld" to my server - page is not found, neither is it in **/var/www**. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This applies to Ubuntu 12.10 (may work with older versions)

First you will need to check that Apache is really using `/var/www` as the website root:

```
$ grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
DocumentRoot <path/to/apache/root_dir>
```

If the path stated in the output is different, you should change that in PHPStorm.

Also you may not be able to place your php files there because the permissions on that folder. To solve this, jst change the permission of `/var/www` (or the correct path) to your current user:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> /var/www
```

where `<user>` is your username.

Comment: Awesome! That worked mate =) But why is folder "read-only" by default? And why none PhpStorm guides tell it?

Comment: The problem is that the folder belongs to the Apache user account (LAMP), so your user could not write to it. This is normal in a production environment, but in a development environment there are no problems if the ownership is changed.

Answer (score 1):

try going to "mapping" and set the mapping options

Comment: Failed to transfer file '/home/chelios/PhpstormProjects/Hosting/index.html': could not write to "file:///var/www/index.html".